# Permalinks Auto Re-Save after every 5 sec

Tags: wordpress, cron, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I am new to coding and trying to fix a problem on a wordpress website.

**Problem:**

Getting 404 error on most pages randomly. If refresh the page, It may load fine but 404 most of the time.

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically save permalinks after 5-10 sec. (admin>settings>permalink)

I know this can be done with a cron job with this code:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

but what I am trying to figure out is a way to add time in it. so it automatically save the permalinks every 5-10 sec.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for it

```
add_action('init', 'saveparmalinkbeforeload');
function saveparmalinkbeforeload(){
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me the code. But when I add this code to the function.php, Website is giving 500 server error.

Comment: I updated the code, please check it now